# ReactJS: How to dynamically render Material-UI's <MenuItem/> inside <DropDownMenu/>?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Using ReactJS + Material-UI, I have an array called `colors` and contains strings of different colors. Say for example the array `colors` has 3 color strings: "white", "blue", "green. Then I would like to render each color string has a `<MenuItem/>` inside a `<DropDownMenu/>` (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu). And once a `<MenuItem/>` is selected, I'd like to console log that particular color like, say chose "white": console.log("white").

So I used .forEach yet the  does not show any strings and it is empty. What could I be doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      value: 1,
    }
  }

  dropDownColorChange(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({value: value})
    //Not sure how to implement here dynamically based on array size. Would like to console.log the color string of the selected
  }

  render() {
    var colors = ["white", "blue", "green"] //would be able to handle any array size


    return (
             <div>
               <DropDownMenu
                value={this.state.valueTwo}
                onChange={this.dropDownColorChange}
              >
                {
                    <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Select" />
                  colors.forEach(color => {
                    <MenuItem primaryText={color}/>
                  })
                }
              </DropDownMenu>
             </div>
    )
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've almost got it right. You have to `map` over available colors and return a `MenuItem` for each color:

```js
const colors = ['white', 'blue', 'green'];

class ColorChanger extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      selectedColorValue: 1,
    };
  }

  handleColorChange(event, index, value) {
    console.log(`You have selected ${colors[value]} color`);

    this.setState({
      selectedColorValue: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDownMenu value={this.state.selectedColorValue} onChange={this.handleColorChange}>
          {colors.map((color, index) =>
            <MenuItem key={index} value={index} primaryText={color} />
          )}
        </DropDownMenu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (contrary to `forEach`) returns an array where each element is the return value of predicate function. In your case it returns a `<MenuItem />`.

Comment: You will need to add `key` property to MenuItem so that React can track each MenuItem

Comment: That's correct, missed this one. The answer is updated.

Comment: I am doing the same but onchange event is not working on dynamically created menuitem any reason why.

Answer (score 0):

I used the react hook to set the menu items on clicking my menu icon and I also set the value I want to pass to my action method.

```
const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = React.useState<IMenuItem[]>();
const [menuValue, setMenuValue] = React.useState<IMenuValue>();

const handleClickMenu = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    value: IMenuValue,
  ) => {
    setMenuItems(value.menuItems);
    setMenuTransaction(value);

    setMenuAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };


return (

// ... code ...
<PositionedVertMenu
 data-testid={`menu`}
 open={Boolean(menuAnchorEl)}
 anchorEl={menuAnchorEl}
 onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => handleClickMenu(event, value)}
 onClose={handleCloseMenu}
>
  {menuValue &&
   menuItems?.map((option, menuIndex) => (
    <MenuItem
     data-testid={`menu-item-${menuIndex}`}
     onClick={() => option.action(menuValue, handleCloseMenu)}
    >
     <Typography>{translate(option.text)}</Typography>
    </MenuItem>
   ))}
 </PositionedVertMenu>
)
```